# SQL Server Select Timestamp, same value, different results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I found this puzzle on Internet, and I have no idea where the problem is.
The following query:

```
SELECT
CAST(‘2015-01-01 14:48:34.69’ AS DATETIME) FirstVal,
CAST(‘2015-01-01 14:48:34:69’ AS DATETIME) SecondVal
```

Returns two different results, why is that?

[image: QueryResults]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at the selects as they are different. The final delimiter in the time in the first one is a . in the second one it's a :.

Per the BOL the first format is correct. The : is being interpreted as Nano seconds? instead of fractions of a second and then converted to a fraction of a second which is why the second select is different.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Those are different date formats, FirstVal has a dot `.69`, SecondVal has `:69`.

`.69` means 0.69 s, equals to 690 ms.
`:69` menas 69 ms.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Good Catch I didn't see that, but what is the difference between both formats?